# Code optimization: How to optimize a code using scipy minimize?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy-optimize

I am trying to optimize a code that I wrote to calculate the least square for a system of equations and returns me the optimal value for the unknowns: `a1,a2,a3,z1,z2` (`pottemp` and `zlevels` are know).

The system of equation is the following (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlKg2.jpg):

[image: System of equations]

I wrote the following code which works like a charm, but it isn't very efficient and you can see due to the number of for loops and if I increase the number of `hstep` and `astep`, my array gets really big and it takes a lot of time to compute the least square from `leastsquared`.

```py
def leastsquared(zlevels,pottemp,z1,z2,a1,a2,a3):
    dtot=0.0
    for zi in range(len(zlevels)): #zvalue of obs points 
        if zlevels[zi]<=z1:
            F=np.tan(a1)*zlevels[zi]+pottemp[0]
        elif zlevels[zi]<=z2:
            F=(np.tan(a1)*z1+pottemp[0]) + np.tan(a2)*(zlevels[zi]-z1)
        else: #zlevels[zi]<=H
            F=((np.tan(a1)*z1+pottemp[0]) + np.tan(a2)*(z2-z1) ) + np.tan(a3)*(zlevels[zi]-z2)
        d=(pottemp[zi]-F)**2.0
        dtot+=d
    dtot=dtot/len(zlevels)
    #print("dtot is" + str(dtot))
    return dtot
```

```py
def optm(hstep,astep,zlevels,pottemp):

    sqdist=np.inf
    for z1 in np.linspace(0,zlevels[-1],hstep):
        for z2 in np.linspace(0,zlevels[-1],hstep):
            for a1 in np.linspace(0,0.1,astep): # max angle
                for a2 in np.linspace(0,0.01,astep):
                    for a3 in np.linspace(0,0.01,astep):
                        sqdist_new=leastsquared(zlevels,pottemp,z1,z2,a1,a2,a3)
                        if sqdist_new<sqdist:
                            sqdist=sqdist_new
                            optimalsetting=[z1,z2,a1,a2,a3]

    return optimalsetting
```

The code itself is very simple but inefficient. I was trying to implement this code using `scipy.optimize.minimize`, but I haven't been able to run it. Does anyone have any idea how to optimize it? Perhaps, `scipy.optimize.minimize` would be the easiest way, but I'm not sure how to adapt my code to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is definitely a more efficient way of dealing with this, since piecewise-linear problems are well studied, but the following is done with `scipy.optimize` as requested. Also scipy can't handle dynamic constraints, such as the requirement that `z1<z2`, so I swapped the order of the variables in the solver if this wasn't enforced. The optimization might be more/less stable by removing these lines of code and let the data speak for itself.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize

def f(zlevels, t0, a1, a2, a3, z1, z2, H):
    """
    Function to evaluate f, given a set of variables
    """
    # Check that no samples are out of bounds
    if any(zlevels < 0) or any(zlevels > H):
        quit("Values of zlevels out of bounds")

    pottemp = np.zeros(zlevels.shape)
    mask1 = zlevels <= z1
    mask2 = (z1 < zlevels) & (zlevels <= z2)
    mask3 = z2 < zlevels

    z1_arr1 = np.ones(sum(mask2))*z1
    z1_arr2 = np.ones(sum(mask3))*z1
    z2_arr = np.ones(sum(mask3))*z2

    pottemp[mask1] = zlevels[mask1] * a1 + t0
    pottemp[mask2] = z1_arr1 * a1 + t0 + a2 * (zlevels[mask2] - z1)
    pottemp[mask3] = z1_arr2 * a1 + t0 + a2 * (z2_arr - z1) + a3 * (zlevels[mask3] - z2)

    return pottemp

def obj_fun(x, zlevels, pottemp, t0, H):
    """
    Least-squares objective function for the problem
    """
    a1, a2, a3, z1, z2 = x
    # Swap order if z1 is larger than z2
    if z1 > z2:
        z1, z2 = z2, z1

    pottemp_pred = f(zlevels, t0, a1, a2, a3, z1, z2, H)
    return sum((pottemp_pred-pottemp)**2) 

def optimize(zlevels, pottemp, t0, H):
    """
    Optimize a1, a2, a3, z1, z2
    """

    starting_guess = [0,0,0,0.5,2.5]
    res = scipy.optimize.minimize(obj_fun, starting_guess, args=(zlevels, pottemp, t0, H), \
            bounds=[(None,None),(None,None),(None,None),(0,H),(0,H)])
    x = res.x
    # Swap order if z1 is larger than z2
    if x[-2] > x[-1]:
        x[-2], x[-1] = x[-1], x[-2]
    return x

# Make the true model for testing
t0 = 0.5
a1 = -1
a2 = +1
a3 = -2
z1 = 1
z2 = 2
H = 3

# Generate some variables
n = 1000
zlevels = np.random.random(n)*3
# Get values and add some random noise
pottemp = f(zlevels, t0, a1, a2, a3, z1, z2, H) + np.random.normal(0,0.1, size=n)

print("Correct values:", a1, a2, a3, z1, z2)
a1, a2, a3, z1, z2 = optimize(zlevels, pottemp, t0, H)
print("Fitted values:", a1, a2, a3, z1, z2)
```

Comment: That's great! But I didn't understand the part where we have ``fvalues`` in ``optmize``. Why should I give this information to the function if that's what I'm looking for? Would it be the initial guesses? Also, t0 is know, but I changed it in the code I tried

Comment: `z` and `fvalues` are the data points that you already have observed and that you're performing the fit against. So given that your form for `f` is correct, `fvalues` corresponds to `f(z)` plus some noise. This corresponds to `zlevels` and `pottemp` in your code, but I was slightly confused about this at the time, as you didn't specify this in the text. I have updated the naming to match your question.

Comment: Oh great! That's what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure of the actual variables and their values. But below is something that I tried:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def leastsquared(zlevels,pottemp,z1,z2,a1,a2,a3):
    dtot=0.0
    for zi in range(len(zlevels)): #zvalue of obs points 
        if zlevels[zi]<=z1:
            F = np.tan(a1)*zlevels[zi]+pottemp[0]
        elif zlevels[zi]<=z2:
            F = (np.tan(a1)*z1+pottemp[0]) + np.tan(a2)*(zlevels[zi]-z1)
        else: #zlevels[zi]<=H
            F=((np.tan(a1)*z1+pottemp[0]) + np.tan(a2)*(z2-z1) ) + np.tan(a3)*(zlevels[zi]-z2)
        d=(pottemp[zi]-F)**2.0
        dtot+=d
    dtot=dtot/len(zlevels)
    #print("dtot is" + str(dtot))
    return dtot

def optm(hstep,astep,zlevels,pottemp):
    steps = np.linspace(0,0.01,astep)
    x0 = np.array([steps, steps, steps]) #a1, a2, a3

    def objective(x):
        return leastsquared(zlevels,pottemp, z1, z2, x[0], x[1], x[2])

    sqdist=np.inf
    for z1 in np.linspace(0,zlevels[-1],hstep):
        for z2 in np.linspace(0,zlevels[-1],hstep):
            sol = minimize(objective, x0, method='SLSQP', options={'disp':True})
            optimalsetting=[z1,z2,sol.x[0],sol.x[1],sol.x[2]]
    return optimalsetting


# test
# some random initialization
astep = 2
steps = 3


optm(5, 2, [1, 2], [1, 2])
```

You might want to update the objective function and variable types here.
Hope this gets you started.

Comment: It works well, but in my case, I need to find the minimum for the least square (optimal value for ``z1,z2,a1,a2,a3`` so it fits my data). This is done in the last part of ``opt`` (``if sqdist_new<sqdist:``). Avoiding this part of the code makes it only loop through ``z1`` and ``z2`` until the end.